# How to send commands to iRobot Create 2?

Tags: irobot-create

I bought a *iRobot Create 2* last week and it does not have any manual to control from my computer, so I have two questions: How can I send commands to my *iRobot Create 2*? And what programs can I do?

Comment: Yeah, I read the manual and I try with a fortware form Delphi that works, I tried with Arduino a,d I received data but I can not sent any command.

Answer (score 1):

There is documentation on the website about this very robot.

```
https://www.irobot.com/about-irobot/stem/create-2/projects
```

I suggest you go to the bottom of the page and look at the Arduino and Raspi `pdf` files that they provide. The Raspi documentation tells you how to command the robot. I think from there you can follow their instructions. I would provide more of an answer, but it seems the OP simply does not know where the docs are for their robot.